# MVC vs Native style in terms of Latency of the system

Tags: laravel, vue.js, model-view-controller, native

Are there any concise proven studies/article on the advantage and disadvantage of Model View Controller (MVC) : in terms of its latency of the system development vs the Native ways?

So let's say I have hundreds of user transact the system at the same time and it causes network latency/delay, what are the advantage of MVC if applied in the system? vs native, Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the meaning of "native" in this context?

Comment: @Estus Flask  like normal languages without using web framework or pattern, such as Java., object c, html , css do you have idea?

Comment: The language is PHP. You shouldn't care about MVC pattern, it's specific implementation matters, not only the framework part but your own code. The advantage of MVC is the design, you can write the code with acceptable performance but minimal amount of mistakes, something you couldn't do if you write it from scratch. The question is too broad for SO and probably anywhere else too. If you're interested about how Laravel performs in terms of RPS, latency, etc, you can research the benchmarks but they are usually synthetic and don't reflect what you have in real-world app

Comment: @Estus Flask Thanks, but it is possible that using laravel MVC in system for example online scheduling system is much more advantage than the native programming languages? in terms of latency? I'm writng research for this but I also need reference to prove the latency and comparison, do you have idea where should I start? It is possible?

Comment: It's totally possible if you can't write a solution that is efficient enough because you'll have to reinvent the wheel and reimplement the functionality of the framework, possibly not in the best possible way. The bottlenecks of real-world web apps come not from a framework but other layers - most often DB. The advantage of using a framework is that you can do a job quicker and likely with better quality and focus on other improvements, including performance. Again, PHP is the language that Laravel is written with, you can't compare HTML to Java, these are apples and oranges.

Comment: You can measure the performance with regular tools like JMeter but the measurements will have no meaning if you don't know what needs to be compared, and why. "Hello world" in Laravel will obviously will be slower than in raw PHP and but this means nothing in terms how a real app would work.

Comment: @Estus Flask I have a system called clinic online scheduling using MVC pattern laravel vuejs and I want to test also their latency differences using bare php native language also named online scheduling , testing it with 100 users simultaneously is it possible in Jmeter?

Comment: Yes. But proceed from the fact that the performance bottleneck belongs to something outside (database or the way it's used in the app like ORM) and you'll have more chances to improve this with caching, etc, and that's where proper design (MVC) is helpful, so it's unclear what's the point of this test.